# PHP mail() not being sent

Tags: php, email

I am attempting to use PHP mail() to send an email with the From address changed.  My example is below...

```
<?php

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Me <me@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";

$message = 'Test Message';

mail("test@test.com","My subject",$message, $headers);

?>
```

No email is ever sent, if I remove the From address then the email gets sent fine.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Check your mail server logs. The destination is possibly rejecting the message because it detects a  forged header.

Comment: Are you **sure** it's not getting sent? It may be getting spam-boxed, bounced (especially if you're sending to an AOL email), or silently ignored. (edit: so basically, what @AlexHowansky said.)

Comment: Additionally are you sending this from a local web server or something like a cPanel server?

Comment: Check your Spambox, it's in there waiting for you; or, your HOST/ISP is blocking it.

Comment: If you are a Windows user this will not work as Windows does not come with a mail server like the nix's. You will have to use something line phpMailer or install a mail server like hMailer.